# powershell function to kill child processes on *nix without Get-CimInstance

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell function `KillChildren` that works on Windows, but not in bash (on my Mac).  The problem is that it uses the windows-only `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet.

Here is the windows-centric version (whose authorship is unknown to me):

```
function KillChildren {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [int[]]$ProcessId,

        [switch]$PassThru
    )

    process {
        foreach ($p in $ProcessId) {
            Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId = '$p' AND NOT Name LIKE 'conhost%'" -Property ProcessId |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId |
                KillChildren -PassThru |
                ForEach-Object {
                    Stop-Process -Id $_ -ErrorAction Ignore -Force
                }

            if ($PassThru -and $PassThru.IsPresent) {
                $p
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How would you write a version of this function that would work in Unix?**

The Unix logic-path can't use `Get-CimInstance`, because that's a windows-specific cmdlet.

This is in an multi-platform repo, and I'm hoping to maintain only a single set of PS scripts, instead of parallel PS and batch scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work **on *Unix*-like platforms to get a given process' child processes** (with the given process identified via its PID (process ID), `$p`) :

```bash
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Parent.Id -eq $p }
```

It **also works on Windows *in principle*, assuming you're running *PowerShell (Core) 7+*** rather than *Windows PowerShell* (where the `Get-Process` output objects have no `.Parent` property), but there's a **pitfall** (which your `Get-CimInstance` solution already (mostly) accounts for - see next section):

- If the process whose child processes to kill is the *current* process and you're running in a regular console window (`conhost.exe`), you must exclude the automatically created `conhost` child process from the results, as killing it too would close the terminal window and therefore kill the target process as well.
- This is *not* a concern in *Windows Terminal*.

---

The following is a **cross-edition, cross-platform solution**:

```bash
# Assumes that $p contains the PID (process ID) of interest.
$(if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
  (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId = $p AND Name != 'conhost.exe'" -Property ProcessId).ProcessId
} else {
  (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Parent.Id -eq $p }).Id
}) # | ...
```

Note:

- At least hypothetically, eliminating *all* `conhost.exe` child processes isn't *fully robust*, because it bears the risk of *false positives* (excluding child processes that shouldn't be excluded),  given that it's possible to explicitly launch `conhost.exe` child processes with commands such as `conhost cmd /k`.

Comment: Thanks!  This got me where I needed to go.