# How to kill all child processes by parent id when parent process shut down?

Tags: powershell

I have a question and I couldn't find appropriate answer after googling so much.

I have an application that uses Selenium, and Selenium starts multiple chrome.exe process.

When I use Windows Task Scheduler to run my app, at the end of task my application process ends correctly, but Selenium (chromedriver.exe) and child processes (chorme.exe) remains running,

I need a script to watch for end of my applications process and after that, kill all of child processes (ParentId= my app process id)

would you please help or guide me ?
Thanks

I set this script from my app

```
var pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
 PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(); 
ps.AddScript(@$" try {{
$continue = 1
do {{
    $process = Get-Process -Id {pId}
    if ($process.count -gt 0) {{
        Write-Output date
        continue;
    }}
    else {{
        $continue = 0
        taskkill /t /F /PId {pId}
    }}
}}
while ( $continue -eq 1)
}} catch {{ Write-Output ""An Error"" }} ");

 ps.InvokeAsync();
```

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896492/terminate-process-tree-in-powershell-given-a-process-id

Answer (score 0):

If you use the PowerShell SDK to execute PowerShell code, it will run *in-process*, so if your application crashes, so will the PowerShell code.

Instead, you'll want to spawn a *separate process* that monitors the lifetime of your process and acts when the latter terminates:

```cs
// Construct a call to powershell.exe, the PowerShell CLI,
// with code that waits for your application to terminate and then
// tries to terminate all of its child processes (except the PowerShell
// child process itself).
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(
  @"powershell.exe",
  @$"-noprofile -c
    $targetPid = {pId}
    try {{ (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore -Id $targetPid).WaitForExit() }} catch {{}}; 
    $childPids = @((Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter \""ParentProcessId = $targetPid\"" -Property ProcessId).ProcessId) -ne $PID
    if (-not $childPids) {{ 'No child processes found' }}
    else {{ Stop-Process -Id $childPids -WhatIf }}
  "
);
// Launch the process asynchronously.
Process.Start(psi);
```

Note:

- The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the `Stop-Process` command above *previews* the operation, which in this case means listing the PIDs of the child processes.
  Remove `-WhatIf` to perform actual termination.
- Note that [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) invariably terminates *forcefully*, without giving the targeted processes a chance to shut down.
- The CIM/WMI-based technique for identifying the child processes was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856493/45375), which also shows a simpler and also cross-platform [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) alternative.